# QT apps do not respect file-chooser bookmarks

Tags: nautilus, files, qt, filemanager, qt5

## background

In ubuntu `files` app (Nautilus), a user can create bookmarks to folders in the left pane:

[image: nautilus in ubuntu 22.04, with user bookmarks]

most apps respect these bookmarks; I assume this is just by virtue of them using a ~ system file-chooser api, which loads the nautilus modal diagram (?).  For example, from firefox, I get this when I save a page:

[image: ubuntu default save-as dialog, WITH user bookmarks]

## problem

Some apps, specifically it appears to be `QT` apps, however, use a different save-as dialog that does not have my bookmarks.  For example, [flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org) and [photoflare](https://github.com/PhotoFlare/photoflare):

[image]

Ideally, this would use the bookmarked folders the user has already set up.  Alternatively, I *would be fine* re-creating them in other "frameworks", provided I don't have to do it often.

How can I get the QT save-as dialogs to have bookmarked folders?  Thanks!

Comment: You don't specifically mention a release, but a picture does say 22.04 or *jammy* so maybe that's what you're using. For my release, and a few selected Qt5 apps I sampled I see the same *bookmarks* in `nautilus` exactly as I do in my Qt5 apps (`pcmanfm-qt`, `featherpad`, `lximage-qt`)...  Your issue maybe those selected apps which are compiled from source?  or how you created those bookmarks.

Comment: This can be solved by forcing the Qt apps to use the XDG desktop portal for GNOME. As for flameshot, this was implemented mid-2022, so 22.04 won't have it. Wait until 24.04, then upgrade

Comment: @guiverc - none of the apps are compiled form source.  For my examples: `flameshot` is their `AppImage` (in order to get latest, which is `v12.1.0` circa 7/2022), and `photoflare` is `v1.6.9` installed via apt (default repos)

Comment: @DanielT - would you mind elaborating?  Is there a way to do this with installed apps?  I'm not familiar with QT; I can see from helptext my flameshot is `qt5`, and over on photoflare's github the latest (NOT same as ubuntu's repos) is also `qt5`

Comment: See https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2628#issuecomment-1138963533 . If upgrading doesn't work, you might need to switch to wayland

Comment: I can't switch to wayland due to no support for barrier/synergy yet (issue is libraries lacking in wayland), but regardless I don't understand the verbiage in your link @DanielT , "only use the portal on wayland", etc.  Does that mean that on wayland, flameshot (specifically, presumably this does NOT cover qt apps in general?) uses the user-definied system file chooser?

Comment: Based on only the evidence in that link, yes, we can only conclude that it applies to flameshot. You would want to test each app to see if it works. "portal" = "user-definied system file chooser"